# In BAT file script, add new line in FILE if FILE doesn't contain that line

Tags: windows, batch-file, hosts

I want to add one line in `hosts` file:

```
127.0.0.1       new-host
```

if it doesn't contain this line.

In `windows` use `bat` scripting.

**Example 1**

before script:

```
127.0.0.1       db
127.0.0.1       host
```

after  script:

```
127.0.0.1       db
127.0.0.1       host
127.0.0.1       new-host
```

**Example 2**

before script:

```
127.0.0.1       db
127.0.0.1       host
127.0.0.1       new-host
```

after script:

```
127.0.0.1       db
127.0.0.1       host
127.0.0.1       new-host
```

My code:

```
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('findstr /c:"new-host" "c:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts"') do set actualLineHost=%%i
echo %actualLineHost%

if "%actualLineHost:"=.%"==".." (
    echo empty
    goto empty
) else (
    echo not empty
    goto notempty
)
```

`findstr /c:"new-host" "c:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts"` works fine in command line returns nothing, but when I run a script a have "not empty" when file doesn't contain line.

Comment: What have you tried, and how has what you've tried failed? Ideally, you should provide a [MCVE] of what you've tried, and include specific information on how it failed, with error messages and/or erroneous output. [SO] is not a code-writing service; the best questions are those which provide useful information so that those who answer can guide you to devising your own correct answer. See [Ask] a Good Question.

Comment: update answer. add my code

Comment: check my answer, tested, and works :)

Comment: Thanks Leo R. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code :

```
@echo off
findstr /m "new-host" C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts
if %errorlevel%==0 (
echo Found!
) else (
echo No matches found
echo 127.0.0.1       new-host >> C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts
)
pause
```

This will launch findstr cmd to search one (or more ) define string in a file, after this, we check if command return error or not, is there is no error, we made an echo to write the line in the file ( >> is for going new line )

Comment: Note: `findstr "string1 string2"` will find each line, that contains *at least one* of the strings. So in OP's examples, it won't add the new line in any case (as `127.0.0.1` is found).

Comment: Edited my  answer, you're right is better only find new-host

Comment: If the hosts file contains the line `#       127.0.0.1       new-host` the intended entry will not be apended because the string will be found but the fact it is commented out will mean that it isn't parsed as required!

Answer (score 0):

Solution without using `errorlevel`

```
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('findstr /c:"new-host" "c:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts"') do goto hostContains
echo 127.0.0.1       new-host >> c:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts
echo "Not found"
goto exit

:hostContains
echo "Found"
:exit
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.